What is the fault in this method of finding second moment of area of a circle
I am trying to find the second moment of area of a circle about a diameter using first principles.
Place the centre of the circle at the origin of XY-plane. Now consider a tiny circular sector with an angle $d\theta$ which makes an angle $\theta$ with the OX-axis. The area of the sector is $dA=\frac12r^2d\theta$. The distance from OX-axis to the centroid of the sector is $y=\frac23r\sin\theta$ (assuming the sector is nearly triangular). Therefore,
\begin{align}
I_{XX}&=\int_A y^2 dA\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac23r\sin\theta\right)^2\left(\frac12r^2d\theta\right)\\
&=\frac29r^4\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac19r^4\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos2\theta) d\theta\\
&=\frac19r^4\left[\theta-\frac{\sin2\theta}2\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac29\pi r^4\end{align}
Why am I not getting the correct answer of $\frac14\pi r^4$?

You did not account for the second moment of the triangle itself.
The parallel axis theorem applies, as it always does.
For this purpose you can treat each segment as a triangle with base parallel to the $x$ axis.
You can then use the formula $bh^3/36$ with
$b = r \csc\theta \,\mathrm d\theta$
and $h = r \sin\theta$.
This gives an additional
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r^4\sin^2\theta}{36}\mathrm d\theta
= \frac{1}{36}\pi r^4,
$$
which is exactly the missing amount.

Usually we get to ignore the parallel axis theorem, not because it is inapplicable to the integral, but rather because we typically take area elements whose height perpendicular to the axis is $\mathrm dy$, and the integral of the second moments of these elements is zero. You chose elements for which this is not true.
Another way to repair your calculation would be to integrate with respect to $\rho$ ($0<\rho<r$) as well as $\theta$.
Try it.
The contribution from the second moments of the area elements is zero in that case too.

Can't we assume that the area of triangle is concentrated to its centriod? Can you please elaborate your point?

No, we cannot just assume the area of the triangle is concentrated at its center of mass, because the integral of second moments of the triangle is non-zero. The parallel axis theorem applies.

Thanks for the clarification. I wonder whether my approach is still valid after this correction, since the question asks to derive it from first principles, and here we use parallel axis theorem as well.

The correction also assumed the second moment of a triangle. I’m not certain what counts as “first principles” for your purposes, but I’d expect it to be a double integral. The last paragraph of my answer hints how to make one within the general layout of your approach.
